# Turn Multiple Column into Json Array in R?

Tags: arrays, json, r, database, postgresql

Say I have the mtcars dataset, and I wanted to take three columns and turn them into a JSON array. How do I convert this to a json array and is that possible to pass them into a POSTGRESQL database?

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- mtcars
attach(mtcars)
json.column <- cbind(mpg,cyl,disp)
```

Do I use toJSON() ?

```
mtcars.json <- toJSON(json.column)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html

Array of objects    [{"name":"Erik", "age":43}, {"name":"Anna", "age":32}]  Data Frame  simplifyDataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your data as a data.frame, not a matrix. Use

```
json.column <- data.frame(mpg,cyl,disp)
toJSON(json.column)
# [{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160},{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160}, ...
```

Also, you should avoid the use of `attach()`. It can cause lots of problems if you forget `detach()`. Plus you can use `with()` often to avoid it

```
json.column <- with(mtcars, data.frame(mpg,cyl,disp))
```

Answer (score 1):

(For starters, never use `attach`! It's dangerous! Use `with` instead, typically.)

There are a bunch of ways to do it. Here's how to create the values using dplyr:

```
qq <- rowwise(mtcars) %>% 
    mutate(newcol=as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(list(mpg=mpg, cyl=cyl, disp=disp))))
> qq$newcol
 [1] "{\"mpg\":[21],\"cyl\":[6],\"disp\":[160]}"     "{\"mpg\":[21],\"cyl\":[6],\"disp\":[160]}"    
 [3] "{\"mpg\":[22.8],\"cyl\":[4],\"disp\":[108]}"   "{\"mpg\":[21.4],\"cyl\":[6],\"disp\":[258]}"  
 ...
```

From there, if your Postgres database is set up with `newcol` as a JSON type, I think just writing that table as usual should work.

Comment: great, I'd love to keep up with dplyr so I can pipe my other preprocessing functions